# How to pass only date from angular 6 to web api

Tags: c#, angular, angular6

I am passing date from my angular 6 application to web api. The problem is when I select for example 10th March 2019 from datepicker. When I get that in web api it's converting it into 9th March 6:30 pm, I think its some with the time zone, but I dont need time I just want to pass date.

Following is angular code

```
  getBookingList() {

    this.bookingListSubscription = this.restService.getBookingListForGrid(this.booking).subscribe(
  data => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (data.status = '200') { 
      this.bookingList = data;
      this.bookingList.forEach((element) => {
        element.StartDate =  this.datePipe.transform(element.StartDate, "dd/MM/yyyy"),
          element.EndDate = new Date(element.EndDate);
      });
    }, 3000)
  });
  }
```

And I am storing date into DateTime format in c#.

Comment: What is the expected format at WebAPI's end? i.e `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Comment: I need only date example if i am selecting 10/03/2019 then it should pass receive the same. In dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: You need to handle timezone in this case. If you do new Date(yourDate) in the backend so it will convert date according to server timezone. Please provide some piece of backend code!

Comment: without time...?

Comment: Yes without time

Comment: @Surjeet Bhadauriya c# web api

Comment: then you can use `DatePipe`

Comment: @prashant could you please help me with sample code as i am new to angular

Comment: @user10884307 Have added an answer please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use angular's [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

Import this:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

and in constructor:

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){}
```

and to change the format of selected date you can simply use transform method:

```
this.datePipe.transform(this.date, "your_expected_date_format"); // Format: dd/MM/yyyy OR dd-MM-yyyy OR yyyy-MM-dd
```

TS Code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';


import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
   providers: [
    DatePipe
  ]
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {

  date : any;
  formatedDate : any;

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){}

  onSubmit(){
   this.formatedDate =  this.datePipe.transform(this.date, "dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
}
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjt8pk)

Comment: getting error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Comment: element.StartDate =  this.datePipe.transform(element.StartDate, "dd/MM/yyyy"),

Comment: I want it of type Date not of string which can be passed to web api and can be stored in DateTime type of c#

Comment: change it to type `any` C# will take that

Comment: changed it to any checked in c# still getting same result date - 5:30 hrs in c#

Comment: Can you produce StackBlitz?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to using [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) would be the use of [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate). I have passed the following values: date, time format, and locale as its parameters.

On your component.ts, you can do something like this:

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

export class AppComponent  {
  locale: string = 'en-US';
  format: string = 'dd-mm-yyyy'
  date: Date = new Date();

  constructor() {}

  transformDate(date) {
    console.log(formatDate(this.date, this.format, this.locale));
    return formatDate(this.date, this.format, this.locale);
  }
}
```

I have reproduced a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-9nstkr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to demonstrate the usage.

Comment: Getting error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Comment: Wait, what? Oh, where did you get that error? What is your input?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, spent lot of time to fix.Instead of sending as datetime type, I sent to backend as a string. Since its Rest API endpoint, automatically converted to Date Time.

```
model.dateOfBirth = new Date(moment(model.dateOfBirth).format('MM/DD/YYYY')).toDateString();
```

This solved my problem.